# How to design a model to allow apply or cancel updates?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there a design or development pattern where we deal with making updates to a copy of the actual data and applying the diff to the original reference if needed?

If not, what is the best way of designing such models?

What I think I should do:

1. I should probably use an enum `mode` to indicate whether the model is being used in 'Update direct reference mode' OR 'Update only a copy mode'
2. Update the setters and getters of data to reference the `actualState` or the `temporaryState` as per what mode is the model being used in.
3. Have the setter method for `mode` to create a copy of the actual data and store it in a temporary state. If the `mode` is updated to `update direct reference`, clear out the `temporaryState`
4. Create a method for applying the changes from `temporaryState` to the `actualState`. This method shall also clear out the temporary state from memory.

In code:

```
enum InsertionMode {
    UPDATE_DIRECT, UPDATE_COPY
}

class Store {
  private Data actualState;
  private Data temporaryState;
  private InsertionMode mode;

  private void resetTemporaryState() {
    ....
  }

  private void initTemporaryState() {
    this.temporaryState = copy(actualState);
  }

  private commitTemporaryState() {
    this.actualState = this.temporaryState;
    this.resetTemporaryState();
  }

  public Data setInsertionMode(InsertionMode mode) {
    if (this.mode != mode) {
        InsertionMode previousMode = this.mode;
        this.mode = mode;

        if (previousMode == InsertionMode.UPDATE_COPY) {
            this.resetTemporaryState();
        }
        if (this.mode == InsertionMode.UPDATE_COPY) {
            this.initTemporaryState();
        }
    }
  }

  public void commit() {
    if (this.mode == InsertionMode.UPDATE_COPY) {
        this.commitTemporaryState();
    }
  }

  public void abort() {
    if (this.mode == InsertionMode.UPDATE_COPY) {
        this.resetTemporaryState();
        this.setInsertionMode(InsertionMode.UPDATE_DIRECT);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think what you have is pretty fine. What's your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just wanted to know if there is a better and cleaner way of achieving this.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @GhostCat. That is exactly what I was thinking. So, if I wanted to maintain the revisions also. This would have been ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given code is "okay", as it will support your requirements.

But: updating objects is a simple approach, and is easy to implement. But depending on your context, you do things really differently in 2017.

Instead of having one mutable object that changes state, you could instead go for immutable objects. State becomes a sequence of such objects.

Reaching a new state means adding a newly created object at the end of the sequence, cancel means to go with the old, unchanged sequence. This approach is the base for [blockchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain) applications; but it can be scaled down to a smaller context as well - just by looking at its core aspect: you never *change* state by changing existing objects, but by creating *new* objects. Of course, this needs a lot of thought; you don't want to blindly duplicate everything; you might more be looking having "delta" objects (that represent individual changes) and "views" that show aggregations of deltas.

Beyond that: you might want to read about CQRS versus CRUD (for example [this](http://blog.softmemes.com/2016/11/12/using-cqrs-with-event-sourcing/)).